Why is the restriction of a self-adjoint operator $A$ to $\mathcal{N}(\lambda - A)^{\perp}$ densely defined?
I have a question regarding the following post:
The restriction of a self-adjoint operator $A$ to ${\mathcal N(\lambda-A)}^\perp$ is symmetric, but is it even self-adjoint?
$A: \mathcal{D}(A) \to H$ is a densely defined, closed and self-adjoint linear operator on the Hilbert space $H$. $A_\lambda$ is the restriction of $A$ on $\mathcal{D}(A) \cap \mathcal{N}(\lambda - A)^{\perp}.$
Why is $A_\lambda$ densely defined there, meaning why should be $\mathcal{D}(A) \cap \mathcal{N}(\lambda - A)^{\perp}$ dense in $\mathcal{N}(\lambda - A)^{\perp}?$

We observe first that $\mathcal{N}(A - \lambda)$ is, by definition, a subspace of $\mathcal{D}(A)$ (as $x \in \mathcal{N}(A - \lambda)$ means $(A - \lambda)x = 0$, and if $x \notin \mathcal{D}(A)$ then $(A - \lambda)x$ wouldn’t even make sense). We further observe it is closed. Indeed, if $\mathcal{N}(A - \lambda) \ni x_n \to x \in H$, then $x_n \in \mathcal{D}(A)$ and $Ax_n = \lambda x_n \to \lambda x$. So by closedness of $A$, $x \in \mathcal{D}(A)$ and $Ax = \lambda x$, i.e., $x \in \mathcal{N}(A - \lambda)$.
Thus, we may let $P: H \to H$ be the orthogonal projection onto $\mathcal{N}(A - \lambda)$. Then $1 - P$ is the orthogonal projection onto $\mathcal{N}(A - \lambda)^\perp$. For any $x \in \mathcal{D}(A)$, as $\mathcal{N}(A - \lambda) \subset \mathcal{D}(A)$, we have $(1 - P)x = x - Px \in \mathcal{D}(A)$. Thus, $(1 - P)(\mathcal{D}(A)) = \mathcal{D}(A) \cap \mathcal{N}(A - \lambda)^\perp$. As $\mathcal{D}(A)$ is dense in $H$, we therefore have $\mathcal{D}(A) \cap \mathcal{N}(A - \lambda)^\perp = (1 - P)(\mathcal{D}(A))$ is dense in $(1 - P)(H) = \mathcal{N}(A - \lambda)^\perp$.

Awesome! Thanks a lot. And this true for every $\lambda in \mathbb{R}.$ So the key point is that  $\mathcal{N}(A- \lambda)$ is a closed subspace of $\mathcal{D}(A),$ if I correctly understood.
So this would work with any closed subspace of $H$ which is a subspace of $\mathcal{D}(A)$ too?

@kumquat Yes, that is correct. If $\mathcal{N}(A - \lambda)$ is replaced by any closed subspace of $H$ which is also contained in $\mathcal{D}(A)$, this would still work. (I wouldn’t call that “closed subspace of $\mathcal{D}(A)$” though. That can be understood as meaning only closed in $\mathcal{D}(A)$, not in $H$.)
